# Mass conversion of numbers in text files using sed

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

Currently, I have multiple files with millions of lines that look like the following:

```
565 0 10 12 23 18 17 25
564 1 7 12 13 16 18 40 29 15
```

The numbers 565 and 564 are ids, and I have extracted all of the unique ids from various files and concatenated them into a single file, looking like the following:

```
565
564
182
982
```

Next, I wish to conduct the following conversion of numbers in the original files:

```
565 -> 1
564 -> 2
182 -> 3
982 -> 4
```

so that the original files will look like:

```
1 0 10 12 23 18 17 25
2 1 7 12 13 16 18 40 29 15
```

I know how to apply a single conversion using sed, but are there any ways to specify the way of conversion in a text file, and use a shell script to apply it to the original files?

Thank you.

Comment: So you have two files. One is original data, the other is unique ids. So conversion happens based on line number of the id, correct ? If 565 is on line 25, then convert every 565 in original file to 25 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to increment the first field in monotonic manner, you do not need to use an extra file for the mapping or the first field, just use `awk` to set the first field as the line (record) number:

```
awk '{$1=NR} 1' file.txt
```

It will rebuild the whole record with space as the new field separator, but in this case i think we are safe as the fields are separated by spaces.

---

Now, here are the ways to solve your problem where you have an extra file let's say `id.txt` with the first fields:

You would be better off using something that can understand line number and keep track of them e.g. `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$0]=NR; next} {$1=a[$1]} 1' id.txt file.txt
```

- assuming, `id.txt` contains the extracted first columns only and `file.txt` is the main file
- `NR==FNR {a[$0]=NR; next}` saves each record of the file `id.txt` as key of associative array `a` with the value being the corresponding line number. `next` ensures no further processing is done to the records of `id.txt`
- `{$1=a[$1]}` sets the first field to the value of corresponding array element; note that, this has the caveat of reconstructing the whole record with space as the separator but i guess in this case we are safe to leverage this brevity. `1` is just a placeholder for interpreting `true` so that the whole record is printed afterwards

---

If you feel fancy, you can use some standard *nix tools, with help from process substitution (`<()`) of `bash` and `paste` finally:

```
paste -d' ' <(nl id.txt | cut -f1) <(cut -d' ' -f2- file.txt)
```

- `nl id.txt | cut -f1` gets the line number
- `cut -d' ' -f2- file.txt` gets all fields but the first

---

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt                                               
565 0 10 12 23 18 17 25
564 1 7 12 13 16 18 40 29 15
182 10 12 23 18 17 25
892 1 7 12 13 16 18 40 29 15

% awk '{$1=NR} 1' file.txt
1 0 10 12 23 18 17 25
2 1 7 12 13 16 18 40 29 15
3 10 12 23 18 17 25
4 1 7 12 13 16 18 40 29 15

% cat id.txt                                                 
565
564
182
892

% awk 'NR==FNR {a[$0]=NR; next} {$1=a[$1]} 1' id.txt file.txt
1 0 10 12 23 18 17 25
2 1 7 12 13 16 18 40 29 15
3 10 12 23 18 17 25
4 1 7 12 13 16 18 40 29 15

% paste -d' ' <(nl id.txt | cut -f1) <(cut -d' ' -f2- file.txt) 
 1 0 10 12 23 18 17 25
 2 1 7 12 13 16 18 40 29 15
 3 10 12 23 18 17 25
 4 1 7 12 13 16 18 40 29 15
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS=""} {print "s/^", $0, "/", ++count, "/"}' > pattern.sed ids.txt
```

It's going to read your "ids" file and creates a list of id's for search and replace using `sed`.

```
$ cat pattern.sed 
s/^564/1/
s/^565/2/
...
```

If your ids are not unique you can use:

```
sort ids.txt | uniq | awk 'BEGIN {OFS=""} {print "s/^", $0, "/", ++count, "/"}' > pattern.sed
```

to make it more efficient, then run:

```
$ sed -i.bk -f pattern.sed file 

$ cat file
2 0 10 12 23 18 17 25
1 1 7 12 13 16 18 40 29 15
1 1 7 12 13 16 18 40 29 11111
1 1 7 12 13 16 18 40 29 15555
2 0 10 12 23 18 17 2555
...
```

If you wish to sort the final file use `sort -k1,1 file > file.sorted`.